# How much internal storage for Apps does Nexus S have?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, internal-storage

I have a Nexus One now, and the internal storage is very limited. For the moment I have only 164 MB internal storage for apps (From DiskUsage).

[Nexus One](http://www.google.com/phone/detail/nexus-one) seem to have totally 512MB of internal storage. And [Nexus S](http://www.google.com/phone/detail/nexus-s) seem to have totally 16GB of internal storage. But Wikipedia wrotes: `16 GB iNAND (partitioned 1 GB internal storage,
15 GB USB storage`

Does this mean that Nexus S only has less than 1GB of internal storage for Apps? I find my 164MB very limiting on Nexus One and I consider to buy a new phone because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus S is only using 1GB of its 16GB memory for internal storage which only left 971MB for applications. This is very limited. I read this from [Test av Google Nexus S](http://www.swedroid.se/test-av-google-nexus-s/) - a deep review in swedish.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the 1 GB is for the /system folder, which is not normally mounted via USB.  The rest of the space is usable for your apps!  I have a Galaxy S and this is how it works, plus there's an external SD card.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds good. Then I can sell my Nexus One with very limited memory (~180MB) for apps and buy a Nexus S with 15GB.

Comment: This was actually false. Only 1GB was dedicated for internal storage and only 971MB of them is avaiable for Apps.

Comment: Then what exactly is the 15gb for?

Comment: You can store data there, use it as a USB-memory and also store applications that is specifictly designed for beeing stored on the SD-card. Far from all applications is designed for SD-card storage, that's why I'm running out of memory on my Nexus One.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Hopefully more and more app developers make their apps support apps2sd.

Comment: Yes, it's false. I experienced it the first-hand. Did you find any solution for this? How to enable this 15Gb for apps?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers (except for Matthew Read's original answer) are completely incorrect. You can choose whether your installed apps are stored on the 1gb system memory or on the 15gb data memory. I have a nexus S and can confirm this is the case. You do not need a rooted phone or apps2sd to do this; it's built-in to the standard build.

Comment: I think this only works if the app is designed for being stored also on SD-cards.

Comment: E.g. see http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=868772